# What is the most appropriate way to initialize a bi-dimensional array of objects?

Tags: c++, c, initialization

I need a dynamically allocated bi-dimensional array of objects.

I declared a static pointer to pointer to object as follows:

```
server_session **server_session::Pglvcl_sess;
```

There's a method to populate dynamically the array of array of object:

```
int server_session::createSession()
{
  int ret = -1;
  // looks for the next available position on the array
  for (int i = 0; i <= MAX_SESSION; i++)
  {
    // if there's an available position, instantiates an object
    if (server_session::Pglvcl_sess[i] == NULL)
    {
      // instantiates object
      server_session::Pglvcl_sess[i] = new server_session();
      ret = i;
      break;
    }
  }
  return ret;
}
```

Should I `malloc` the  `server_session::Pglvcl_sess` variable?

What is the proper way to initialize it?

**EDIT:**

The application executes this method at startup, is this OK?

```
void server_session::initializeSessions()
{
  server_session::Pglvcl_sess = ( server_session * * )   malloc(MAX_SESSION * sizeof(server_session));
  for (int i = 0; i <= MAX_SESSION; i++)
  {
    if (server_session::Pglvcl_sess[i] != NULL)
    {
      server_session::Pglvcl_sess[i] = NULL;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any reason not to use

```
Vector<Vector<server_session> >
```

and let it do the dynamic allocation and management for you?

Comment: @Michael Dorgan, I was having trouble with a library compiled in pure c. I had segmentation fault's using Vector calling the functions from this lib. I don't know if it's related, but using pointer to pointer it worked...

Answer (score 1):

In case you really want an array instead of a vector, use std::tr1::array (or std::array or boost::array, all the same).